# Posterior of an iid sample withh distribution $Pois(\theta)$ and a prior of $Exp(\lambda)$

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

I have a sample $X_1,…, X_n$ that are iid with $Pois(\theta)$ as their distribution where $Θ = ℝ^+$. Now, suppose that the prior distribution of $$ is $Exp(\lambda)$. I am given the solution as follows:

The likelihood function is:

$L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^{x_i}}{x_i!} = \frac{e^{-n\theta} \theta^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i!}$

As such, the posterior distribution is:
$f(\theta|\mathbf{x}) = \frac{\frac{e^{-n\theta} \theta^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i!} \times \frac{1}{\lambda}e^\frac{-\theta}{\lambda}}{\int_0^\infty  \frac{e^{-n\theta} \theta^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i!} \times \frac{1}{\lambda}e^\frac{-\theta}{\lambda} d\theta}$

My question is, why is the prior distribution written as $\frac{1}{\lambda}e^\frac{-\theta}{\lambda}$ and not $\frac{1}{\lambda}e^\frac{-x}{\lambda}$? Isn't the probability density function of $Exp(\lambda)$ distribution $\frac{1}{\lambda}e^\frac{-x}{\lambda}$? So where did $\theta$ come from?

Comment: Please read the description of the tag '[distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory)'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with Bayesian Statistic. Your parameter (unknown parameter $\theta$) **has its own distribution**. In particular your prior is an $Exp(\lambda)$ and the variable is exactly $\theta$

Moreover, the solution can be derive in a faster way

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})\propto \pi(\theta)p(\mathbf{x}|\theta)$$

Thus

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})\propto e^{-n \theta}\theta^{\Sigma x} e^{-\frac{\theta}{\lambda}}=\theta^{\Sigma x}e^{-\theta(n+\frac{1}{\lambda})}$$

We immediately recognize that

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})\sim \mathrm{Gamma}\Big(\Sigma x+1;n+\frac{1}{\lambda}\Big)
\qquad (1) 
}
$$

All the calculations you showed are not necessary and tedious

In fact all the quantities not depending on $\theta$ can be removed because they are included in the normalization constant...also you denominator does not depend on $\theta$ because it is integrated over all $\Theta$

Having derived that the posterior (1) is a Gamma with the specified parameters, the normalization constant is immediately given, thus the complete expression of your posterior is

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})=\frac{(n+\frac{1}{\lambda})^{\Sigma x+1}}{\Gamma(\Sigma x+1)}\theta^{\Sigma x}e^{-\theta(n+\frac{1}{\lambda})}
\qquad (2) 
}
$$

In the density (2) the variable is $\theta \in (0;+\infty)$; $\lambda$ is a parameter, while $n$ and $\Sigma x$ are given observed data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes sense. But does the formula $π(θ|\textbf{x}) ∝ π(θ)p(\textbf{x}|θ)$ apply to all posterior questions?

Comment: @VirgOpta Yes, of course. Applying Bayes Theorem (as you did) you have to divide by $p(\mathbf{x})$ but not depending on $\theta$ do not take care of it... first multiply likelihood by prior and try to recognize a known density. In case you can't...then you are compelled to solve the integral as you did in your procedure...

Comment: Thank you so much!