# Finding the gamma integral for a sample of $iid$ $Bin(1, )$ random variables with $Θ = [0, 1]$, and a prior of $$ distributed as $U[0, 1]$

Tags: binomial-distribution, bayesian

I am given $X_1,…, X_n$ as a sample of $iid$ $Bin(1, )$ random variables
where $Θ = [0, 1]$, and we are assuming that the prior distribution of  is $U[0, 1]$

Therefore, the likelihood function for the observed sample is

$L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \theta^{x_i}(1-\theta)^{1-x_i} = \theta^{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}(1-\theta)^{n-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}$

Therefore, the posterior is written as follows:

$f(\theta|\textbf{x}) = \frac{\theta^{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}(1-\theta)^{n-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}}{\int_0^1 \theta^{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}(1-\theta)^{n-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}d\theta} = \frac{\theta^{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}(1-\theta)^{n-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}}{\frac{\Gamma(1 + \sum_{i=1}^nx_i)\Gamma(n-1 + \sum_{i=1}^nx_i)}{\Gamma(n+2)}}$

My question is how did we know that the $ \int_0^1 \theta^{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}(1-\theta)^{n-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}d\theta = \frac{\Gamma(1 + \sum_{i=1}^nx_i)\Gamma(n-1 + \sum_{i=1}^nx_i)}{\Gamma(n+2)}$?

Is there a formula or a general pattern for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posterior can be easily found remembering, [as usual](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3907288/posterior-of-an-iid-sample-withh-distribution-pois-theta-and-a-prior-of-exp),  that

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{
\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})\propto \pi(\theta)\times p(\mathbf{x}|\theta)
\
}
$$

Thus, being $\pi(\theta)=1$, you have

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})\propto \theta^{\Sigma x}(1-\theta)^{n-\Sigma x}\sim Beta(\Sigma x+1;n-\Sigma x+1)$$

Now, remembering how the analytical expression of a [Beta density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) is, the complete analytical expression of your posterior is

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{
Beta(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}\theta^{a-1}(1-\theta)^{b-1}
\qquad (1) 
}
$$

Substituting (1) in your exercise you get immediately

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})=\frac{\Gamma(n+2)}{\Gamma(\Sigma x+1)\Gamma(n-\Sigma x+1)}\theta^{\Sigma x}(1-\theta)^{n-\Sigma x}$$

---

The result of your integral is wrong. At a certain point you wrote $\Gamma(n-1+\Sigma x)$ while the correct expression is $\Gamma(n-\Sigma x+1)$

Comment: I see, makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much again!

Comment: @VirgOpta : you're welcome! It is a matter of doing some exercises because Bayesian Thinking is a little different from the Classical one and probabily you are still not familiar with it. If in trouble do not hesitate to post your exercises...

Comment: I don't know how much more I can thank you. You're right about me not being familiar with Bayesian Thinking, I started learning it 2 days ago. I will most likely post more questions about my exercises because I'm the type of person that needs to do A LOT of practice to fully grasp any new concept in general. So I will need to do a lot of practice to fully grasp the concepts of Bayesian Thinking and more practice => (Almost Definitely) more questions. Thanks Again!!!